# What are cameras that allow you to change the lens called?

Tags: camera-basics

recently my friend was talking about a specific type of camera, which can be used with or without the additional lenses. Can you please tell me what these camera type is called as?

Comment: That would be any camera surely? You can add an additional lens to anything

Comment: That would be any camera capable of taking a picture, I guess.

Comment: By "without [the] additional lenses", do you mean, "without buying additional lenses"?

Comment: Broadly speaking, I think what your asking about would be Interchangeable Lens Cameras. It used to be that there were just SLR-type cameras that allowed you to change lenses. Today, there are a variety of cameras that support interchangeable lenses, some with mirrors (DSLR's) and some without (the host of "Mirrorless" digital cameras). Mirrorless are smaller and cheaper, and these days often not quite as capable, DSLR's are larger and more expensive and are about as capable as a camera gets.

Answer (score 8):

Any camera that allows you to change the lens is an **interchangeable lens camera**. This is an extremely broad category these days, as it includes 3/4 format cameras, SLRs, SLTs or mirrorless cameras, medium format and large format cameras.

The type of camera that probably springs to most people's mind when talking about a camera with interchangeable lenses is the SLR - single lens reflex - camera.

Comment: Although, I'm sure your answer is what the OP was asking for - he says it can be used without additional lenses. With that in mind, it could be one of the many bigger point/shoot cameras that allow adapters and other optics to attach in front of the built-in lens.